# How to show stdout and stderr in different consoles in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

During developing, I don't want to redirect them into files. Is there any way to create two consoles, one only displays stdout messages while another only displays stderr? Is there any plug-in that can provide this feature?

Comment: Are you asking this in the context of Eclipse plug-in development or as general user of Eclipse. If you can write the Plug-in code yes this can be possible creating seperate consoles for seperate outputs.

Comment: General user of eclipse. But is there any plug-in that can separate them?

Comment: This actually seems like a good idea for a plugin (if there isn't one already).

Comment: @ Jermaine Xu: As per my knowledge there is no readily availble plugin for this, but as a plug-in developer it is very simple to create one for this requirement. Check the link :http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best you can do it to use different colors in the text for stdout and stderr. But there is only one Console view that is used for output.

Comment: can you plz explain, how to do this